# Explicitly define/use a namespace instead of an inferred one based on the project directory structure

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

How can I create an explicit common pseudo namespace for independent packages, to avoid naming collisions, without nesting them in sub-directories which use implicit namespaces?

For example, I want the packages to be part of the `foo.bar` namespace (`foo.bar.package1`, `foo.bar.package2`, etc.) without having to nest them 3 levels deep:

**package1 using implicit namespace:**

```
foo
  bar
    package1
      __init__.py
pyproject.toml
```

**package2 using implicit namespace**:

```
foo
  bar
    package2
      __init__.py
pyproject.toml
```

Each package should be in its own project/repo and installable separately.

For projects that depend on these packages, I would also like the ability to use `from foo import bar` and have the independent packages referenced as `bar.package1`, `bar.package2`, etc.

Comment: The main problem here is that both `foo` and `foo.bar` are namespace packages, and the modules inside them are found via path search normally, which is why the directory structure is required for PEP 420 namespace packages. There might be some hacks but I think thwarting typical packaging structures is usually only going to end up as a lot more difficult. Is there a reason you don't want the 3 level deep folder structure? Perhaps there's a different way to achieve the same end goal you're after?

Comment: Note the other methods mentioned in the Python docs: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#creating-a-namespace-package. In particular `pkgutil.extend_path()` might be sufficient for you.

Comment: @alkasm it's certainly looking like it's going to be very messy trying to hack around it, especially if I want autocompletion to play nicely in VSCode etc. I just find it strange/superfluous having to use multiple empty directories to neatly categorise related packages instead of being able to simply define the package as being part of a particular namespace directly (like many other languages). PEP 20 suggests explicit is better than implicit, but then again it also advocates flat over nested designs, so I may be better off simplifying things... :)